# Rails 3: How to merge queries or scopes for complex query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

I'm building an events app that is very simple, it has a **title** and **start_date** and **end_date**. I would like to filter my query by mixing some of the values, like: if the start_date has passed but the end_date has not, the event is active and should be displayed. If both dates have passed, it should be omitted, too. I think that scopes is the aswer, but I only was able to filter the records within the view using some methods shown below.

I really would like to filter the query that is passed to the controller (@events). **I want to show all events that are active, have a future start_date, or a past start_date but are still in progress (Today's date is in range between start_date and end_date)**

### EDITED

I have made some scopes which return each part of the query. Chaining them actually substracts the results instead of merging them. So i have used this code and **actually works** do I do not know how solid or DRY this is. Looks kind of ugly to me... is this a decent way to merge queries in rails 3?

```
scope :active, where("active = ?", true)
scope :not_over_or_in_progress, lambda { where("start_date < ? AND end_date > ? OR end_date IS NULL AND start_date > ? OR end_date IS NOT NULL AND start_date > ?", Date.today,  Date.today, Date.today, Date.today) }
scope :valid, not_over_or_in_progress.active.order("start_date DESC")
```

Comment: Now that you have the scopes, if you want to merge the results then do a union: Event.active | Event.in_progress(Date.today). Note that this will produce a regular old array instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation object. ie. you won't be able to chain further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using scopes:

```
class Event < AR::Base
  scope :active, lambda { |date| where("start_date < ? AND end_date > ?", date) }
  scope :future, lambda { |date| where("end_date < ?", date }
  ...
end

# Console
> @active_events = Event.active(Date.today)
> @future_events = Event.future(Date.today)
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I've added some more code to my question based on your sugestions, but still lack the ability to merge the queries or scopes. If I chain them active.in_progess.single, I get 2 results, instead of the result of a merge (more results)

Comment: Made some improvements and have worked it out thanks to your sugestions, but not sure if the code is solid, still. Can you comment on it?